# iTunes Search API, finding Free prices

Tags: objective-c, ios

When searching the iTunes store, I've hit a little problem. I'm trying to change the text of my label to "FREE" when the price is 0.00, as opposed to displaying the price. The problem is, my comparison of the two `NSDecimalNumber`s fails. Here's where I am currently at.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[formatter setCurrencyCode:self.searchResult.currency];
NSString *price = [formatter stringFromNumber:self.searchResult.price];

NSDecimalNumber *free = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:0.00f];

NSLog(@"Price:%@",price);
NSLog(@"Free:%@",free);
NSLog(@"self.searchResult.price: %@", self.searchResult.price);

if (self.searchResult.price == free) {
    NSString *freeText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"FREE"];
    self.priceLabel.text = freeText;
}
else {
    self.priceLabel.text = price;
}
NSLog(@"priceLabel:%@", self.priceLabel.text);
```

What's really weird is that the Console even says that both `free` and `del.searchResult.price` are the same:

```
2012-11-24 20:01:16.178 StoreSearch[1987:c07] Price:$0.00
2012-11-24 20:01:16.178 StoreSearch[1987:c07] Free:0
2012-11-24 20:01:16.178 StoreSearch[1987:c07] self.searchResult.price: 0
2012-11-24 20:01:16.179 StoreSearch[1987:c07] priceLabel:$0.00
```

I'm a little confused by this to be frank. Any help would be appreciated. If you could explain why this has happened so that I can learn not to do it again, then I'd be even more grateful!

Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got NSNumber and another NSNumber (NSDecimalNumber) and you do a pointer equal check you either need need to call isEqual or compare the primitive float values

== with objects doesnt compare the value but the object pointer (the memory address)

---

```
if(searchResult.price.floatValue == free.floatValue)
```

*note that a float is inprecise and generally should not be used for any calculation or comparison. It is ok in this case though*

Comment: Perfect! I knew I was missing something. What a stupid mistake. Still struggling to get my 'C' days behind me. Thanks again.